# partial overlap of images in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

How to achieve partial overlap of 2 images in android. Please do check http://cl.ly/KB8R

I am trying to use both frame and relative layout but unable to achieve this look and feel .

Comment: I think negative ``android:layout_marginTop`` for lower ImageView will give desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: if all of your screen is filled by this two image, let the first imageview align parent top.

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

and let the second imageview align parent bottom.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

2: otherwise, you should make one of your imageview fixed and give it an id like this.

```
android:id="@+id/image1"
```

and let image2 align top of image1 and do it.

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image1"
android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
```